# What are password encryption schemes that result in variable length common in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: passwords, hash, php, mysql, decryption

I have stumbled across passwords on a MySQL database behind a PHP webapp. Here are some examples.

753a524d56b48d825328ce27
789e0ad30d15
7ba0868c23e0a2
d327e265ca2abcd7c
48276b3d5618850
bffaa9b3ba92ffc3
21614da133d56e72857c
44d2059e642f97333

Apparently they are of different length each, so I would conclude that they are not hashed.
Another thing that strikes me is the seeming overrepresentation of numerals.
One can also observe the same symbol twice in a row fairly often.
Additionaly they are mostly within the range of common password lengths.

I have tried cracking the password using auto-detection and various frameworks errored out since they could not detect the encryption method autmoatically.

Does anybody have an idea as to what encryption scheme might have been used here?

Comment: Why would you blindly guess what it is instead of looking at the applications source code for how it is generated and used?

Comment: Have you tried running this thru `hashid`, `hashidentifier` and similar tools? Including online ones.

Comment: yes, to no avail.